# Wierd Problems With My Own Custom Written Word Search Algorithm

Tags: c, arrays, string

My sister and I recently got an assignment in C to write a function which finds a specific word in a string, and if found, returns the first letter index of that word found in the string. But all sorts of problems popped up...

### Main File [testing_word_search.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "u_s_search_word_in_string.h"

int main()
{
    int first_letter_idx = 0;

    char line[32] = "Janen is a dog";
    char word[4] = "dog";

    first_letter_idx = search_word_in_string( line, word );

    printf("\nThe beginning of the word is at index %d.\n", first_letter_idx );

    return 0;

};
```

### Functions [u_s_search_word_in_string.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "u_s_search_word_in_string.h"

int search_word_in_string ( char line[], /* ( Input ) */
                           char word[]  /* ( Input ) Word to search for in {line}. )
{
    int line_idx = 1;
    int word_idx = 1;
    int first_letter_idx = 0;

    /* Finding word. */

    while ( (line[line_idx] != '\0') )
    {
        if ( (line[line_idx] = word[word_idx]) && (word[word_idx] != '\0') )
        {

        /* Index of beginning letter of word set to another variable. */

            if ( (first_letter_idx = 0) )
            {
                first_letter_idx = line_idx;
            }

            line_idx++;
            word_idx++;

        }
        else
        {
        /* If word turns out to be not found, continue. */

            first_letter_idx = 0;

            line_idx++;
            word_idx++;

        };

    };

    if ( (first_letter_idx = 0) )
    {
        puts("Cannot find word in string.");
        return -1;
    };

    if ( first_letter_idx >= 1 )
    {
        puts("Found word, returning first letter index.");
    };

    return (first_letter_idx);

};
```

### Function's header file. [u_s_search_word_in_string.h]

```
int search_word_in_string ( char line[], /* ( Input ) */
                        char word[]  /* ( Input ) Word to search for in {line}. */ );
```

Sorry if the comments may seem crappy, I will work on them later, but I don't know what is wrong...

First of all, when compiling there isn't a warning about using Puts(), second, the compile tells me everything was successful but when I execute it, this happens:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./testing_word_search: not found
```

My inputed build command:

> Compile: gcc -Wall -c testing_word_search.c
>   u_s_search_word_in_string.c Build: gcc -o word_search 
>   testing_word_search.o u_s_search_word_in_string.o Execute: "./%e"

Usual default setting, I know that if I want to run a program I must go to the main module.

And when I run it using the terminal, it says this:

```
 The beginning of the word is at index 0.
```

There should be another message other then this technically.

I would really be thankful if one of you members points out my mistake, because so far, I am clueless as to what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: You should be careful about logical operators: testing equality is done with operator `==`, whereas operator `=` is for assignment. First review your code with that in mind, it should correct some errors!

Comment: index should be 0 start.

Comment: As @BLUEPIXY said, but in more words: you do realize that indexing a C array starts with `0`, i.e. that's the index of the array's first element, right? You set the initial index to `1` and use `0` to mean "nothing", which is not right. You will never look at the first character, that way.

Comment: You may want to look at [**Substring in C without functions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098263/substring-in-c-without-using-functions/27100208#27100208) It is for a similar assignment, but may provide ideas for finding the substing that can be easily adapted to what you need. (the normal way to do it would be to use `strstr` and then dereference the return...)

Comment: `word_idx` You must be reset if it fails to matching.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with your code:

1. You don't need semicolons after a block of statements (i.e. after the closing bracket `}`).
2. You have to compare your chars via `==` and not via `=` (first is a comparison, second is an assignment).
3. `line_idx` and `word_idx` should be zero (because the string you are looking for can also exist at the beginning).
4. `first_letter_idx` should default to -1 (because, again, 0 is a valid value), and you should check for -1 and not for 0 to know if the search failed.
5. The rest seems okay, but you can shorten your code a bit (e.g. the check `word[word_idx] != '\0'` is unnecessary; also `line_idx++;` and `word_idx++;` can be written beneath the if-else statement, because they get executed no matter what happens.)

I hope this solves most of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The header `string.h` provides a function `strstr` that is tailor made for what you are trying to accomplish. Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char *string = NULL;
    char *substr = NULL;
    char *p = NULL;

    printf ("\nEnter string : ");
    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &string);

    printf ("\nEnter substr : ");
    scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &substr);

    if ((p = strstr (string, substr)) != NULL)
        printf ("\nSubstring found beginning at : %c (char '%lu' in string)\n\n", 
                *p, p - string + 1);
    else
        printf ("\nSubstring NOT in string.\n\n");

    if (string) free (string);
    if (substr) free (substr);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/strstrc

Enter string : Janen is a dog

Enter substr : dog

Substring found beginning at : d (char '12' in string)
```

If you must do it without using `strstr`, then the link in the comment will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int search_word_in_string ( char line[], /* ( Input ) */
                           char word[] )
{
    int line_idx = 0;
    int k;
    int word_idx = 0;
    int first_letter_idx = 0;

    /* Finding word. */

    while ( (line[line_idx] != '\0') )
    {
        word_idx =0;
        if(line[line_idx] == word[word_idx])
        {
            k = line_idx;
            while(word[word_idx] != '\0' && word[word_idx] == line[k])
            {
                k++;
                word_idx++;
            }
            if((k-line_idx) == strlen(word))
            return line_idx+1;
        }
          line_idx++;
    }

    return -1;

}

int main()
{
    int first_letter_idx = 0;

    char line[32] = "Janen is a dog";
    char word[4] = "is";

    first_letter_idx = search_word_in_string( line, word );

if(first_letter_idx > -1)
    printf("\nThe beginning of the word is at index %d.\n", first_letter_idx );
    else
    printf("\n String not found \n");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you Philipp and Bluepixy, I updated my code:

```
/*
 * Author: Usia, Sebastian
 * Date: 21/NOV/2014
 * 
 * Input: Two character type variables.
 * Output: Index number of beginning letter of word.
 * 
 * Description: Uses an algorithm to find a word in a string and if found
 * it returns the index number of the first letter of the found word.
 * 
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#include "u_s_search_word_in_string.h"

int search_word_in_string ( char line[], /* ( Input ) */
                        char word[]  /* ( Input ) Word to search for in {line}. */ )
{
    int line_idx = 0;
    int word_idx = 0;
    int first_letter_idx = 0;

    int word_length = 0;
    int matched = 0; /* Number of consecutive characters matching between {word} and {line}. */ 

    /* Find {word}'s length. */

    while (word [word_length] != '\0') word_length++; 

    printf("word length is %d\n", word_length);

    /* Finding word. */

    while ( (line[line_idx] != '\0') && (matched != word_length) )
    {

        printf("before IF: line_idx = %d, word_idx = %d\n", line_idx, word_idx);

        if ( (word[word_idx] != '\0') && (line[line_idx] == word[word_idx]) )
        {
            printf("*match* line_idx = %d, word_idx = %d\n", line_idx, word_idx);

            /* Marking {word}'s first letter in the text line. */

            if ( (word_idx == 0) )
            {
                first_letter_idx = line_idx;
            }

            matched++;
            word_idx++;

        }

        else
        {

        printf("letters do not match --- line_idx = %d, word_idx = %d\n",line_idx,     word_idx);

            /* If letters don't match, reset word_idx and match counter. */

            word_idx = 0;
            matched = 0;        

        };

        line_idx++; /* No matter what we move ahead the {line_idx}. */
    };


    printf("matched %d\n", matched ); 
    if ( matched == word_length )
    {
        printf("Found word, returning first letter index.");
        return (first_letter_idx);
    }
    else    
    {   
        printf("Cannot find word in string.");
        return -1;
    };

};
```

Added traces just to be sure.

I never really heard of "strstr" before, I will check it out sometime soon. Thanks again.